# Will an iPhone only activate using the SIM card that it was originally activated with?

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

I read [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34869/using-iphone-as-ipod-touch) and was wondering if I need to have a SIM card that has previously activated an iPhone in order to activate an iPhone.

I'm inheriting my mother's old 3Gs to use as an iPod / for development purposes, and I was wondering if when I restore it to factory settings I'll need her old SIM card to activate it.

Comment: Of course - the best course of action is to inherit the SIM along with the phone - the person giving the phone can usually ask the carrier for a new SIM or ensure it's no longer billing to their account and you can use the old SIM and phone without needing service.

Comment: Sadly my mother has already switched to a 4S and has had her SIM card cut to fit her new phone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - any valid SIM from the correct carrier will activate a phone that is locked to one carrier.

In the rarer case - iPhone 3G was sold or is now authorized unlocked in which case, you don't need any SIM to activate the device after a restore operation.

If the device is carrier locked (in the US - AT&T is the likely carrier), you can either buy a valid SIM from the correct carrier. A prepaid line or locating the SIM that was last used to activate the phone are good options for low expense.

Apple has articles that can guide you in this process:

- [Using an iPhone without a wireless service plan](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3406) - This covers setting up an old iPhone like an iPod touch.
- [iOS: How to back up your data and set up as a new device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4137) - The end of this covers restore, set up as new and more explanation of carrier plans.
- [About swapping the SIM card](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2309)
- [iPhone: Troubleshooting authorized unlock issues](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3198)

Comment: I think the device it likely to be unlocked as it was bought in the middle east.

Comment: Excellent - you don't need a sim then to activate the device. I'll link two more articles so the main answer is more complete